# Method Range of object Global failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I keep getting a method range of object __global error for my code, even though I have initialised the worksheet and ensured that the name is correct. Any help? The code is supposed to be finding a range of cells with data in to be put into a second spreadsheet

```
Sub potential()

'Add hours for potential work to generate function

Sheets("Resourcing Sit-Rep").Select

p = Range("Potential person").End(xlDown).Row - Range("Potential person").Row
For k = 1 To p

    For j = 1 To 187
        If Range("hours").Offset(k, j).Value > 0 Then

        Sheets("Resource Forecast").Select
            Val5 = Range("Potential person").Offset(k, 1).Value
            Val6 = Range("Potential person").Offset(k).Value
            Val7 = Range("hours").Offset(k, j).Value
            Val8 = Range("date").Offset(0, j).Value

        Sheets("Resourcing Sit-Rep").Select
            A = Range("Leader").Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown).Row - Range("Leader").Offset(0, 2).Row + 1

            Range("Leader").Offset(A, 2).Formula = Sheets("Resource Forecast").Range("Project_Number").Value & " (" & Sheets("Resource Forecast").Range("Project_Name").Value & ") - " & Val5 & " POTENTIAL WORK"
            Range("Leader").Offset(A, 3).Formula = Val6
            Range("Leader").Offset(A, 4).Formula = Val7 / 7.5
            Range("Leader").Offset(A, 5).Formula = Val8

         Else

         End If

    Next j

Next k
'Range("Leader").Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4", Cells(Range("Leader").Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown).Row, 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd say is that you should always qualify your ranges with specifics worksheet objects.

But your issue is that this:

`Range("Potential person")` doesnt work.
The Range Method cannot find such a range.

Excel Named Ranges cannot have spaces in them, so either your ranges have underscores or something. Try with simple test without spaces, and you should make progress.

Comment: I have removed the spaces but that had no effect, the error reappeared

Comment: Range name has to be exactly the same in VBA code as the named Range in Excel. Is this the case? Otherwise can you debug, and let us know which line the error is occurring on??

Comment: Exactly the same name, I've tried changing the name, changing the sheet it's on but nothing seems to work

Comment: The Ranges have been qualified by sheets? Sheet1.Range("Pol_Pot") etc??

Comment: What do you mean qualified? I've selected the worksheet that I am working in, which the data comes from